# mallet inferencer for hLDA

Tags: mallet

I'm trying to use hLDA to create a topic model and then to make inferences based on that model. But as far as I've seen, the topic inferencer tool only works  on LDA models, am I right? Is there a way of inferencing topics from a hLDA model?

Answer (score 2):

I found an hLDA Inferencer [here](https://github.com/chyikwei/topicModels/tree/master/hLDA) from chyikwei on Github that I believe will get you there.

I've tested it and have successfully (I think) used it to score new documents.

Following the MALLET build instructions [here](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/download.php), I rebuilt MALLET with the `HierarchicalLDAInferencer.java` code in src/cc/mallet/topics following chyikwei's [README](https://github.com/chyikwei/topicModels)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out [this](http://mallet-dev.cs.umass.narkive.com/BfCPOri8/using-mallet-command-tool-to-execute-hda-topic-model)?

```
\mallet run cc.mallet.topics.tui.HierarchicalLDATUI --input [FILENAME] --output-state [FILENAME]
```

worked for me.