# cmd for hLDA topic modeling in mallet

Tags: mallet

I am trying to use hLDA for topic modeling in mallet.Ihave already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38376278/mallet-inferencer-for-hlda). Using cmd

```
bin\mallet train-topics  --input tutorial.mallet
```

according to this[tutorial](http://programminghistorian.org/lessons/topic-modeling-and-mallet). By default LDA topic modeling is being performed. How can I change it into hLDA?
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: I found the answer [here](http://mallet-dev.cs.umass.narkive.com/BfCPOri8/using-mallet-command-tool-to-execute-hda-topic-model). the cmd is: \mallet run cc.mallet.topics.tui.HierarchicalLDATUI --input [FILENAME] --output-state [FILENAME]

Answer (score 0):

Use Mallet version 2.0.7 and then

bin/mallet hlda --input tutorial.mallet